Equivalence classes of rational sequences (not only Cauchy ones)
A standard construction of $\mathbb{R}$ is as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences over $\mathbb{Q}$, with two sequences equivalent iff their pointwise difference has a limit of $0$. My question is, does the set of equivalence classes of all rational sequences (not just Cauchy ones) have any interesting properties or interpretation? Apologies if this is too open-ended a question for here.
As far as I can tell, this set defines:

a commutative ring (with $[(a_n)] + [(b_n)] = [(a_n) + (b_n)]$ pointwise, etc), but not a field
with a natural partial order ($[(a_n)] < [(b_n)]$ iff $(b_n) - (a_n)$ eventually $\geq \epsilon > 0$)
and zero divisors (e.g. $[(0, 1, 0, 1, \dots)] \times [(1, 0, 1, 0, \dots)] = 0$), including orthogonal idempotents but no nilpotents

Is there anything else interesting to be said? Do the elements have any natural interpretation (beyond "equivalent sequences")?
Update: as noted in the comments, equivalence classes of unbounded sequences do not in fact form a ring (e.g. $(\frac{1}{n}) \times (n) \neq (0) \times (n)$). Oops.

Why do you think it is a ring? There might be problems with multiplication, e.g. $\frac{1}{n} \approx 0$, but $n \cdot \frac{1}{n} \not \approx n \cdot 0$ (so $\left[ 0 \right] \cdot [n]$ is ill-defined). It's definitely a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, though (because scalars are fixed).

As Adayah says in the comments, there are problems with multiplication. Things are better if you work with bounded sequences rather than all sequences. Then you can replace rational sequences with real sequences (since every real sequence is equivalent to a rational sequence), and then as explained here, the result is a commutative real $C^{\ast}$-algebra isomorphic to the $C^{\ast}$-algebra of continuous real-valued functions on the corona $\beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ where $\beta \mathbb{N}$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$, also known as the space of non-principal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$.
Concretely what this means is that given a bounded sequence $a_n$ we can take its limit $\lim_U a_n$ with respect to any non-principal ultrafilter $U$ on $\mathbb{N}$, and the result is invariant under replacing $a_n$ with an equivalent sequence. These limits are a family of ring homomorphisms and in fact give all $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphisms from this $\mathbb{R}$-algebra to $\mathbb{R}$.
